# Error when accessing access the WSDL of my WCF services: "The ... operation references a message element … that has already been exported from the …"

Tags: wcf, wsdl, mex

I experience a weird behavior when accessing my web services into a web browser and it leads to an exception while generating.

Here is my scenario:

1. Access web page: http://localhost:10100/WCFService1.svc?wsdl
2. Access web page: http://localhost:10100/WCFService2.svc?wsdl

The problem is that the output of WCFService2.svc WSDL contains all the definition of WCFService1 merged with WCFService2.

Furthermore, when I access another WSDL which contains a method having the same name of previously generated WSDL, I get this exception (surely because my WSDL are being merged together).

I also notice the name of the contract is kind of weird having the ":" before the service name: http://MyCompany.ca/:IWCFService3

Someone have a clue what is going on with the "WSDL export extension"?

---

> An ExceptionDetail, likely created by
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true,
>   whose value is:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown in a call to a
>   WSDL export extension:
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior
>   contract: http://MyCompany.ca/:IWCFService3
>   ----> System.InvalidOperationException: The
>   MyCompany.IWCFService3.Import
>   operation references a message element
>   [http://MyCompany.ca/:Import] that has
>   already been exported from the
>   MyCompany.IWCFService2.Import
>   operation. You can change the name of
>   one of the operations by changing the
>   method name or using the Name property
>   of OperationContractAttribute.
>   Alternatively, you can control the
>   element name in greater detail using
>   the MessageContract programming model.
>       at System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractExporter.AddElementToSchema(XmlSchemaElement
>   element, String elementNs,
>   XmlSchemaSet schemaSet)
>       at System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractExporter.ExportWrappedPart(Message
>   message, String elementName, String
>   elementNs, XmlSchemaSet schemaSet,
>   Boolean skipSchemaExport)
>       at System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractExporter.ExportBody(Int32
>   messageIndex, Object state)
>       at System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractExporter.ExportMessage(Int32
>   messageIndex, Object state)
>       at System.ServiceModel.Description.MessageContractExporter.ExportMessageContract()
>       at System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior.System.ServiceModel.Description.IWsdlExportExtension.ExportContract(WsdlExporter
>   exporter,
>   WsdlContractConversionContext
>   contractContext)
>       at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.CallExtension(WsdlContractConversionContext
>   contractContext, IWsdlExportExtension
>   extension)

Comment: I would suggest you try this with two (small) dummy services, reproduce the problem, then post the code here.

Answer (score 2):

I found my problem: We have a huge set of Web Services and we were having a single instance of System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataBehavior that we were sharing among all the services. Making a new instance of ServiceMetadataBehavior for each service fixed the issue.